# R - rbinom; what does the probability of success define if there is N number of observation?

Tags: r

In R, you can generate the data from multinomial distribution using rbinom. For example, if you do

```
  rbinom(400, 1, 0.2)
```

It generates 400 points of 0 or 1 with the probability of 0.2 that the data point is 1. So, the second argument is the number of trials, but I don't exactly know that that means. What is the number of trials? If I set this to be 1, I see the values of 0 or 1, and if I set it to be N, I see the values of 0 - N.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `size` is the total number of trials, of which `size*prob` are expected to be successes.

```
rbinom(400, size = 10, prob = 0.2)
```

gives the results of 400 runs of 10 coin flips each, returning the number of successes in each run.

So, `rbinom(1, 10, 0.2)` has the same expected value as `sum(rbinom(10, 1, 0.2))`.