# Parameters of rbinom() in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm new to R, and it's been a while for me and statistics. I don't understand what the parameters of rbinom are. What's is the difference between n (="number of observations") and size (="number of trials")?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643165/r-rbinom-what-does-the-probability-of-success-define-if-there-is-n-number-of) question is related, but I don't understand the answer there.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Each random draw from rbinom represents the number of successes in a given number of trials (size). For example if size = 3 and p = 0.5, a single random draw would be the number of heads you would get in 3 coin flips. If n = 10, the "3 coin flips" are repeated 10 times and rbinom gives you a vector of 10 numbers, each representing the number of heads in 3 coin flips (for a total of n*size=30 coin flips).

Comment: THANK YOU! So each "observation" has "trials" in it. The number of observations is "n", the number of trials per observation is "size", and the output is a vector of length "n" where each value is how many of the trials in that observation "succeeded".

Answer (score 2):

A binomial distribution usually has two parameters, an integer which indicates the number of attempts and so the maximum possible value (here called the size) and a success probability for each attempt between 0 and 1.  The expectation is then the product of these two parameters.

For a random sample from this distribution, you are also interested in having a particular number of observations.

So in `rbinom(n, size, prob)` you have

- `n` being the number of sample observations
- `size` being the integer parameter of the binomial distribution, using 1 if you want a Bernoulli distribution
- `prob` for the probability parameter of the binomial distribution

As an example, you might get

```
set.seed(2021)
rbinom(5, 100, 0.2)
# 19 23 22 19 21
```